# How to show that if $[x]=v$ then $\left|x-v\right|<\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

How to show that if $[x]=v$ then :

$$\left|x-v\right|\le\frac{1}{2}$$

Where $ []$ is the [nearest Integer Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NearestIntegerFunction.html).

I know how to round a real number,but how to prove this?it looks simple,however I could not prove that.

Comment: You will need a $\le$ sign. The converse is true though: *if* $|x-v| < \frac{1}{2}$ and $v$ is an integer, then $v$ is the nearest integer to $x$.

Comment: Generally $x=v+f$ where $-0.5\leq f < 0.5$ or the otherway $-0.5 < f \leq 0.5$ depending on the definition of $[]$

Answer (score 1):

If by contradiction we would have $\lvert x - v \rvert > \frac{1}{2}$ that would mean that either $x > v + \frac{1}{2}$ or $x < v - \frac{1}{2}$. In the first case the $v + 1$ would be a better approximation of $x$ and in the second it would be $v - 1$ as we would have $\lvert x - (v + 1) \rvert < \frac{1}{2}$ in the first case and $\lvert x - (v - 1) \rvert < \frac{1}{2}$ in the second one.

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong. Say $x = 2.5$ and $v = 2$. Then $[x] = v$ but $|x - v| = \frac{1}{2} \not< \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: so if I change it to "if $[x]=v$ then $\left|x-v\right|\le \frac{1}{2}$" then is that right?

Comment: yes, as Bartek answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3676148/577325

Comment: So either $x\ge v$ or $x<v$,When $[x]=v$ there are two cases,either $$v\le x<v+\frac{1}{2} \;\;\;\text{or}\;\;\; v-\frac{1}{2}\le x< v$$$$\iff$$ $$0\le x-v<\frac{1}{2} \;\;\;\text{or}\;\;\; -\frac{1}{2} \le x-v<0$$ But I can't say that $\left|x-v\right|\le\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Actually you can.
$0\leq x-v \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $0 \leq -(x-v) \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $|x-v|$ is either $x-v$ or $-(x-v)$.

Comment: Yes you are right,the inequality is not just sharp from the right,but it's true

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $x=v+f$ where $0\le f<1$

$$|x-v|=|f|$$ which is be $<\dfrac12$

$$\iff0\le f<\dfrac12$$

But $\dfrac12\le f<1,$   $$|x-v|\ge\dfrac12$$

Comment: So either $x\ge v$ or $x<v$,When $[x]=v$ there are two cases,either $$v\le x<v+\frac{1}{2} \;\;\;\text{or}\;\;\; v-\frac{1}{2}\le x< v$$$$\iff$$ $$0\le x-v<\frac{1}{2} \;\;\;\text{or}\;\;\; -\frac{1}{2} \le x-v<0$$ But I can't say that $\left|x-v\right|\le\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @user715522, As $$f\ge0, x\ge v$$